# Graphing rows with a date value within 50 days of a given value in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have a DataFrame (dataframeA) with column of dates, all formatted like this

date
19960826
19960826
19970303
19970320
19970905

and a column of values
values
100
35
11
37
...

and a column of groups
groupK
groupL
groupM
...

Given another DataFrame, dataframeB, with two columns: date in the format yyyymmdd, and group. For each row in dataframeB, how do I graph the values that are within 60 days before and after the date for each group.

i.e. if dataframeB first  row is
20050101     groupM

graph (on the Y axis) the values in dataframeA where the date is within 50 days before or after Jan 01 2005, and the group is groupM.

Comment: This would be soooo much better with sample data.  Otherwise, I'd not waste my time making up an example.  That's just me.  Someone else may be willing to help.  For help maximizing your chance of having your question answered, read [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [***HowToAsk***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @piRSquared I understand that not having all of the data makes this tougher, I was trying to be as minimal as I could. even understanding how to get the rows in range given a date would be hugely helpful. I can figure out the graphing and the iteration, really stumped on that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample data to start with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

start_date = '20050101'
drange = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=100, freq='D')
possible_groups = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
chosen = np.random.choice(possible_groups, len(drange), replace=True)
groups = pd.Series(chosen).apply(lambda x: 'group'+x)
values = np.random.randint(1, 100, len(drange))

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'date':drange, 'grp':groups, 'value':values})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'date':drange, 'grp':groups})
```

*Note*: If you need to keep the datetime objects visually looking like `YYYYMMDD`, you can use `strftime()` and switch back to datetime as needed, e.g.:

```
drange = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=100, freq='D').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Now, assuming you need to keep these data frames separate for some reason (i.e. `merge()` is not allowed), the following should work.

```
def plot_range(data, within):
    (
     dfA.set_index('date')
        .loc[dfA.grp.values == data.grp]
        .loc[data.date-pd.Timedelta(days=within):
             data.date+pd.Timedelta(days=within)]
        .plot(title=data.grp)
    )

within = 50 # set within to the desired range in days around a date
dfB.apply(plot_range, axis='columns', args=(within,))
```

Here's example output from a few days' subset:

```
subset = 3
within = 10
dfB.sample(subset).apply(plot_range, axis='columns', args=(within,))
```

[image: time series plot]